# Spring Security - auto login not working after registering user

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

In my Spring Boot MVC application I used Spring Security to provide authentication and users registration. Authentication and registration of users are working correctly, but after creating user account I want to login him automatically. While doing this I am receiving BadCredentialsException. This user with the same credentials normally is correctly login in with the login form. I appreciate any help from you. Below is my code:

**Method from controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result,
                           WebRequest request, Errors errors) {
    User registeredUser = null;
    if (result.hasErrors() == false) {
        registeredUser = createUserAccount(user, result);
    }
    if (registeredUser == null) {
        return "/register";
    }
    securityService.autologin(registeredUser.getLogin(), registeredUser.getPassword());

    return "/whiprounds";
}
```

**SecurityServiceImpl (method authenticate is throwing exception)**

```
 @Service
public class SecurityServiceImpl implements SecurityService {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityServiceImpl.class);

    @Override
    public String findLoggedInLogin() {
        Object userDetails = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails();
        if (userDetails instanceof UserDetails) {
            return ((UserDetails) userDetails).getUsername();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void autologin(String username, String password) {
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());

        authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);

        if (usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.isAuthenticated()) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            logger.debug(String.format("Auto login %s successfully!", username));
        }
    }
}
```

**UserServiceImpl**

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Override
    public User registerNewUserAccount(User user) throws LoginExistsException {
        if (loginExists(user.getLogin())) {
            throw new LoginExistsException("User with this login already exists");
        }
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.setRoles(new HashSet<>((Collection<? extends Role>) roleRepository.findAll()));

        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    private boolean loginExists(String login) {
        User user = userRepository.findByLogin(login);
        if (user != null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**UserDetailsServiceImpl**

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByLogin(s);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(s);
        }

        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
        for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getLogin(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First of all**, this method throwing an exception because of the password problem (As far as I can see from your code). Your method `registerNewUserAccount` returning `User` object which password has already been hashed. Then you passing it here:

```
securityService.autologin(registeredUser.getLogin(), registeredUser.getPassword());
```

So it turns out that you're passing hashed password into `authenticationManager` later. This is wrong - you should pass original password into it. Smth like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result,
                       WebRequest request, Errors errors) {
    User registeredUser = null;
    String originalPassword = user.getPassword();
    if (result.hasErrors() == false) {
        registeredUser = createUserAccount(user, result);
    }
    if (registeredUser == null) {
        return "/register";
    }
    securityService.autologin(registeredUser.getLogin(), originalPassword);

    return "/whiprounds";
}
```

**Second of all**, `authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);` - this method actually returns filled `Authentication` object (if authentication was successful), and you should put this object into `SecurityContext`, and not the one you've passed to `authenticationManager'. Smth like this:

```
@Override
public void autologin(String username, String password) {
    UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());

    Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);

    if (auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        logger.debug(String.format("Auto login %s successfully!", username));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.